# How to consider all lines in a matrix?

Tags: r

I have a matrix like this:

```
  mat
        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]       [,4]       [,5]         
   1271 "04"     "7"      "-01"      "08"      "W"
```

Now I want to use these information:

```
    paste0("path","nhg","_",mat[1], "_", mat[2], "_", mat[3] , "_", mat[5] ))
```

## no problem with that

but for this case (I do not know how many rows I have):

```
mat <- matrix(c("21", "343", "86", "0486", "W2",
  "21", "33",  "16", "02",  "n9",
  "11", "343", "16", "693", "n07"), byrow=TRUE, ncol=5)
mat
#      [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4]   [,5] 
# [1,] "21" "343" "86" "0486" "W2" 
# [2,] "21" "33"  "16" "02"   "n9" 
# [3,] "11" "343" "16" "693"  "n07"
```

SO I want to repeat this: `paste0("path","nhg","_",mat[1], "_", mat[2], "_", mat[3] , "_", mat[5] ))` for each row.

Comment: you want to paste column `paste(mat[,1],mat[,2],mat[,3],sep="_")` or something like that

Comment: just apply  `paste0("path"...........` as many as rows I have using info from each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

`apply(mat, 1, function(x){paste0("path","nhg","_",x[1], "_", x[2], "_", x[3] , "_", x[5] )})`

edit: a bit too late I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your request correctly this should work:

```
mat <- matrix(c("21", "343", "86", "0486", "W2",
                  "21", "33",  "16", "02",  "n9",
                  "11", "343", "16", "693", "n07"), byrow=TRUE, ncol=5) 
f <- function(vec) {paste0("path","nhg_", paste0(vec, collapse="_"))}
apply(mat, 1, f)

# [1] "pathnhg_21_343_86_0486_W2" "pathnhg_21_33_16_02_n9"    "pathnhg_11_343_16_693_n07"
```

Comment: if you get the `paste0` out of the `apply` it can be much more compact: `paste0('pathnhg',apply(mat, 1,paste,collapse="_"))`